# Sampling edges with shared end nodes

Tags: python, graph, machine-learning, networkx

I am implementing a NN training algorithm in tensorflow which requires sampling the input of the neural network from a graph, in particular I want to create mini batches of edges taken from the graph, randomly selected from a neighborhood region - i.e. that share some end nodes.

Right now, I have a generator that returns a batch of edges at random from all the edges in the graph. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

I think that there should be a way to partition the graph into list of neighboring edges using networkx and then randomly pick from these partition untill all edges have been sampled...

Thank you in advance for any input on this

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple graph:

```
import networkx as nx
D = nx.Graph()
D.add_path([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

Partition the graph into list of neighbouring edges by node:

```
partitions = list()
visited = set()
for node in D.nodes():
    if node not in visited:
        adjacent_edges = D.edges(node)
        partitions.append(adjacent_edges)
        for u, v in adjacent_edges:
            visited.add(u)
            visited.add(v)
```

As you can see `partitions` is a list of partitions by edges.

> [[(1, 2)],
>
> [(3, 2), (3, 4)],
>
> [(5, 4), (5, 6)],
>
> [(7, 8), (7, 6)],
>
> [(9, 8)]]

Now, you want to randomly pick from these partitions until all edges are exhausted. This approach shuffles partition in place to achieve randomness.

```
import random
for partition in partitions:
    random.shuffle(partition)
    for edge in partition:
        print(edge)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's brilliant and very simple.  For the sake of completeness I would like to add that to truly sample at random before shuffling each partition a `random.shuffle(partitions)` should be added.